# Minecraft 1.8.9 doesn't work, although 1.14.4 does

Tags: games, minecraft

I am on Ubuntu version 18.04.3, and I can play Minecraft 1.14.4 just fine but other versions such as 1.8.9 I cannot play on. I have the output log [here](https://pastebin.com/cC07uDG1):

```
20:04:08.232
Preparing to launch minecraft client for 1.8.9
20:04:08.391
Checking installations.
20:04:08.391
Minecraft client 1.8.9 is ready to start.
20:04:08.391
Starting!
20:04:08.403
Using default game log configuration client-1.7.xml (outputs XML)
20:04:09.630
Setting user: purpledog124
20:04:09.643
(Session ID is token:######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################)
20:04:11.179
Skipping bad option: key_key.attack:key.mouse.left
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.use:key.mouse.right
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.forward:key.keyboard.w
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.left:key.keyboard.a
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.back:key.keyboard.s
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.right:key.keyboard.d
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.jump:key.keyboard.space
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.sneak:key.keyboard.left.shift
20:04:11.180
Skipping bad option: key_key.sprint:key.keyboard.r
20:04:11.181
Skipping bad option: key_key.drop:key.keyboard.q
20:04:11.181
Skipping bad option: key_key.inventory:key.keyboard.e
20:04:11.182
Skipping bad option: key_key.chat:key.keyboard.enter
20:04:11.182
Skipping bad option: key_key.playerlist:key.keyboard.tab
20:04:11.182
Skipping bad option: key_key.pickItem:key.mouse.middle
20:04:11.182
Skipping bad option: key_key.command:key.keyboard.slash
20:04:11.183
Skipping bad option: key_key.screenshot:key.keyboard.f2
20:04:11.183
Skipping bad option: key_key.togglePerspective:key.keyboard.f
20:04:11.183
Skipping bad option: key_key.smoothCamera:key.keyboard.unknown
20:04:11.184
Skipping bad option: key_key.fullscreen:key.keyboard.f11
20:04:11.184
Skipping bad option: key_key.spectatorOutlines:key.keyboard.unknown
20:04:11.185
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.1:key.keyboard.1
20:04:11.185
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.2:key.keyboard.2
20:04:11.186
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.3:key.keyboard.3
20:04:11.186
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.4:key.keyboard.4
20:04:11.186
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.5:key.keyboard.5
20:04:11.187
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.6:key.keyboard.6
20:04:11.187
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.7:key.keyboard.7
20:04:11.187
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.8:key.keyboard.8
20:04:11.187
Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.9:key.keyboard.9
20:04:11.193
LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
20:04:11.235

Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 111: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
20:04:11.235
Process crashed with exit code 127
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: `java --version` please. Edit your question for output.

Comment: I already fixed it, it was using jdk 11 but I was supposed to use jdk 8 for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to make a folder just for 1.8, in `/home/blabla/.minecraft`.

Run `mkdir 1.8folder` and change it in the Minecraft launcher.